# how to change the tksheet language in tkinter?

Tags: tkinter

Good afternoon, please tell me. How do I change the language of the table in the tksheet library?
tksheet  [documentation](https://github.com/ragardner/tksheet)

[image]

```
from tksheet import Sheet
import tkinter as tk


class demo(tk.Tk):
  def __init__(self):
    tk.Tk.__init__(self)
    self.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.frame = tk.Frame(self)
    self.frame.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
    self.sheet = Sheet(self.frame,
                   data = [[f"Row {r}, Column {c}\nnewline1\nnewline2" for c in 
    range(50)] for r in range(500)])
    self.sheet.enable_bindings()
    self.frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")
    self.sheet.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky = "nswe")


app = demo()
app.mainloop()
```